# Firefox not respecting font-weight with service mark character

Tags: css, firefox, browser, rendering, typography

I'm working on a web app where I need to display a service mark character (℠). The stylesheet has a `font-weight` of 300 for the tag where the character is rendered. When rendered at this weight, the service mark character seems to become abnormally large and slightly thicker than one would expect given the appearance of the trademark character (™) at the same weight. The behavior is more pronounced when a `font-weight` of 100 or 200 is used.

Below is a test document which demonstrates the behavior. The output on Firefox 12.0 on OS X [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0v5A.jpg) (sorry, too new to attach image inline). This behavior seems to persist regardless of `font-family` used. Chrome 19.0.1084.52 on OS X also displays the service- and trademarks with some inconsistency across weights, but the effect is much less noticeable.

Is this a bug with Firefox/Gecko, or am I doing something wrong here? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Service Mark Test</title>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-type' />
  </head>
  <body style="font-family:sans-serif;">
    <p style="font-weight:normal;">Here is a normal service mark&#8480; and trademark&#8482;</p>
    <p style="font-weight:100;">Here is a weight 100 service mark&#8480; and trademark&#8482; <span style="color:red;">(unexpected)</span></p>
    <p style="font-weight:200;">Here is a weight 200 service mark&#8480; and trademark&#8482; <span style="color:red;">(unexpected)</span></p>
    <p style="font-weight:300;">Here is a weight 300 service mark&#8480; and trademark&#8482; <span style="color:red;">(unexpected)</span></p>
    <p style="font-weight:400;">Here is a weight 400 service mark&#8480; and trademark&#8482;</p>
    <p style="font-weight:500;">Here is a weight 500 service mark&#8480; and trademark&#8482;</p>
    <p style="font-weight:600;">Here is a weight 600 service mark&#8480; and trademark&#8482;</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the font family setting to e.g.

```
font-family: Calibri, Arial Unicode MS, Lucida Sans Unicode,
  DejaVu Sans, FreeSans, sans-serif;
```

This is a font problem: when you use just the generic name `sans-serif`, each browser will use its own default sans serif font. This is typically Arial, which does not contain the service mark character. Browsers will be forced to use fallback fonts, and Firefox apparently uses different fallback fonts for different font weights—this is a bit strange, but surely possible.

The list above contains specific fonts that contain the service mark character. Most of those fonts have just one or two font weights, as most fonts, really. Even the bold version of e.g. Arial Unicode MS is “fake bold” (algorithmically bolded normal font), but the result is usually tolerable, though not pretty.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I had tried Arial and Helvetica, but I suppose those don't have the service mark character either. Thanks for providing examples that do contain the character.

Comment: The Fileformat.info site contains information about font support to characters, e.g. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2120/fontsupport.htm (The information is not quite complete but covers the commonly available fonts pretty well. However, some fonts, most notably Arial Unicode MS, exist in different versions; newer versions may have essentially wider character coverage.)

Answer (score 0):

I found this which may help answer your question.

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/character_famsupp_197.html

As you see font-weight: 100 is pushing the font as thin as it can go, while 400 is normal, 700 is bold.

In between can make very little difference and in most cases 100 - 500 are exactly the same to the majority of font families.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's good to know. What I think is different about this case, though, is that at widths 100-300, FF is using an abnormally large and heavy rendering. Even larger and heavier than the rendering seen at the normal or bold weights. If it were simply that it were using the "nearest available" rendering for the intermediate weights, then it would be a different story.